# How to connect to facebook

Tags: php

I have made a site in which i have to connect to facebook site such that when user click on registration form in my site then a popup will open of facebook site login page & when he login in facebook site then he will login automatically in my site also. I have no idea how can i start this in my site.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to implement Facebook Connect for that. Have a look at these tutorials on how to implement that:

- http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/tutorial.php
- http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=593212676601 (Video)

Answer (score 0):

It may also be useful to read the title "Single Sign-on with the JavaScript SDK" at [Facebook's developer documentation of authentication.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Facebook SDK's [JavaScript Based authentication tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/javascript) may also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also think about [OpenId's](http://openid.net/get-an-openid)

You can authendicate people with their openid,with out creating brand new username and password.

i think there is possibility to do the same with facebook,

if you really going to do lot of operation once after the facebook login you go with facebook documentation,else you just refer about openid standerds.